GTranslate widget on WordPress website showing at bottom of page in mobile view
I'm trying to get the translate button to float on the screen in mobile view.(like it does in desktop view) Currently it is sitting permanently at the bottom of the page.
Is there some customer CSS what will allow me to do this?
Cant seem to see anyway to edit Gtranslate Pugin just for mobile view

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
